# How can one convert an XFile image from any format to a JPG image for upload?

Tags: flutter, dart

Right now I'm able to chose an image as `XFile` using MultiImage picker as follows:

```
final List<XFile>? images = await _picker.pickMultiImage(maxWidth: _maxWidth, maxHeight:_maxHeight);
```

which then gives me a list of images which I am able to send into my upload service for uploading to my server

```
                      for (var image in images)
                      {
                         await myUploadService(image);  //image is an XFile
                      }
```

Now what I need to do is convert the images, no matter what format they are in, into a JPG image before the upload

So I have tried to convert the images, using the image Flutter package (https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image) as follows:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ImageConvert;

                      for (var image in images)
                      {

                        //Convert all images to JPG
                        final newImage = ImageConvert.decodeImage(File(image.path).readAsBytesSync())!;
                        var newImg = ImageConvert.encodeJpg(newImage);

                        var newImg2 = Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(newImg)) as XFile; // <--- the main problem
                         
                        await myUploadService(newImg2);

                       }
```

But this isn't working, mainly at the point where I try to put the image back into an XFile format for upload with my upload service

So the main question is here is how can I convert the newly encoded JPG image back to XFile format?

Open to totally different strategies of dealing with this issue as well

Comment: You can do a XFile.fromData(Uint8List bytes) to convert a Uint8List value into XFile.

Comment: @WilsonToribio `The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.`  It appears that newImg is coming out as a List<int>

Comment: in that case use Uint8List.fromList( List<int>) to convert the List<int> bytes into a valid Uint8List them you can use that data.

Comment: You got List<XFile> from the _picker.pickMultiImage then you are trying to convert the XFile to Image (object) then agin convert the Image to XFile and upload the XFile via myUploadService. Why don't you use directly XFile to upload via _picker.pickMultiImage. I mean why you convert XFile to Image and reconvert again Image to XFile?